# Strange behavior with java strings

Tags: java

I have two string variables ticker and detail. I'm trying to print out the two strings in one line. It just wouldn't work. I've tried so many different ways of doing this. To exclude the possibility of an uninitialized string I tried printing them out in different lines ... this works.

This example works ... except that the output needs to be in one line.

```
            System.out.println(ticker);
            System.out.println(detail);
```

And the output is:

```
IWM
|0#0.0|0#0.0|0#-4252#386|
GLD
|0#0.0|0#0.0|0#-4704#818|
```

When I try to put the output into one line in any of many ways, I get only the ticker ... the detail string is just not printed ... not to console or to file. Here are some example code snippets that produce the same result:

Attempt 1:

```
 System.out.println(ticker.concat(detail));
```

Attempt 2:

```
System.out.println(ticker+detail);
```

Attempt 3:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append(ticker);
sb.append(detail);
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Attempt 4:

```
System.out.print(ticker);
System.out.println(detail);
```

In all the above attempts, I get the following output ... as if the detail part is ignored:

```
GOLD
BBL
SI
```

What could be causing these symptoms? Is there a way to get the two strings printed in one line?

Comment: I don't see how the first output and the last output are related. They don't contain the same thing at all. You're probably not printing what you think you're printing. Try making a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: yes, this is run in real time, so the outputs are slightly different, but the format is some ticker stored in ticker ... an some detail stored in detail variable.

Comment: Could you show us the actual content of the `ticker` and `detail` Strings? You could debug the code and get the text there...

Comment: What does it mean? Is there a fictional time?

Comment: The first printed statement matches what is shown in the debugger.

Comment: I meant the content, like : `IWM\n|0#0...`

Comment: What does this print?  'System.out.println(detail.length());' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be better suited as a comment, but then I couldn't write the code snippet I need to write.

Where do the Strings come from? Are they from a file that might contain some odd control characters? If you're not creating the String yourself, you should examine them to look for embedded vertical carriage returns or other weirdness. Do something like this for both the `detail` and `ticker` Strings:

```
for (int i=0; i<detail.length(); ++i)
    System.out.println((int) detail.charAt(i));
```

and see if you get anything in the non-ASCII range.

Comment: that is an interesting thought ... I'll run the test.

Comment: there are a bunch of 0s ... I guess the system doesn't delete the 0s and assumes that terminates the string. I'll work on that idea. Is there a standard library routine to get rid of trailing zeros?

Comment: ASCII NUL definitely counts as weirdness! If you can strip those off before creating the Java String objects, I bet your problem will go away.

Comment: the problem starts with the construction of ticker with String(bar) where bar is a byte[] ... the String constructor from byte[] doesn't eliminate the trailing 0s ... seems like a design flaw to me ... I mean who would want to construct a string with trailing zeros?

Comment: You are using byte values for characters, it's not the system's fault if you put wrong values in it.

Comment: OK ... if that is the policy, then when concatenating strings, who would want whatever is past the \0 ? Its not very intuitive to me, if someone really needs to hide information behind a \0, then they should have to do the hard work of keeping track of details. I think the majority of ppl dont' want to hear about what follows the trailing 0 ... my opinion of course :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having byte 0x00 in Java strings, so why would the constructor need to ignore them.

Comment: Indeed, that's the thing. Java Strings are *not* NUL-terminated like C strings are, and *technically* 0 characters are just fine. In practice, they cause weird artifacts when printing or otherwise interacting with an outside world that expects NUL to indicate the end of something.

Comment: Well, there is the "definition" of a string and then there is "practical" usage. I think the wrong thing is leading in the Java String definition, unless I"m missing some important purpose of the trailing 0s, or some inconvenient side effect of the more "usable" alternative.

Answer (score 2):

May be the first string ends with a "\n", the newline (line feed) character ('\u000A')